# How to configure Spring Boot microservices with Netflix Eureka in GCP Cloud Run?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, microservices, google-cloud-run, netflix-eureka

I had my work microservices with Spring Gateway and Netflix eureka in docker, but now I want to switch to GCP Cloud Run.
I'm running into a problem where my microservices register with the Eureka service, but then can't talk to each other.

I want to make requests from my Front-end to ApiGw, but 500 status code is returned
API GW log:  `"textPayload": "io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8080"`

Work microservice log: `INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.commons.util.InetUtils         : Cannot determine local hostname"`.

May be its because they registers with just localhost because it can't find actual hostname and port: [eureka screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUcGx.png), but for Cloud Run there must be URL, like https://helloworld-xyzxyzxyz-ew.a.run.app

Eureka application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server
server:
  port: 8761

eureka: 
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
```

API GW eureka config:

```
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URL}
```

Work microservice eureka config:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URL}
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
```

I tried to use `instance: preferIpAddress: true` in apiGw, but it didn't helped